# Unable to create overlay with ActivityIndicator on React-Native application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I am having a requirement where I need to create overlay with disabled background using React-Native's ActivityIndicator, the functionality is working fine but I am finding it hard to create overlay that too at the centre of the screen because of my code structure

Code

```
<ScrollView alwaysBounceHorizontal={false} horizontal={false} contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  <View>
    <Test1 listData={testData1} />
    <Spacing />
    <Test2 listData={testData2} />
  </View >}
</ScrollView>
```

Test1 and Test2 are two independent list components

Comment: Put the overlay outside the ScrollView? You aren't showing enough code, and I don't know what you mean by 'overlay with disabled background'.

Comment: @BenButterworth I mean loader with opaque background and disabled for any events